# Typing Block matrix between texts than in separated picture?

Tags: matrices

How can I type a block matrix for instances a square that divided on each side
between lines in LaTeX? Namely between `$...$`?

Comment: Could you add an example of what you are trying to achieve? An [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of what you have tried so far would be useful as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [easybmat](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/easybmat) package.

Comment: Let say we have three matrix A,B,C then in multiplication  C=A*B we have M_ij:=(A_ij,B_ij,C_ij)

Comment: Sorry, this comment doesn't make sense to me at all.

Comment: Let say we have three matrix A,B,C then in multiplication  C=A*B we have M_ij:=(A_ij,B_ij,C_ij) such that each A_ij/B_ij/C_ijs are agian block matrices.. So I want to say sth like "(A_01,B_10,C_00)=(...,...,...)" that use the structure of subblocks like sqaure of a square that partitioned only in one quarter, so on...

Comment: @Mohammad: Still does not make sense to me. This is another case that shows that it is always best to provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem.

Comment: And such Minimal Example can be an image from Paintbrush or Word or whatever, showing how you want it all arranged.